# minimum window of a string using only the first occurrence of a letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, window, substring, enumerate

the problem says i have to find the minimum window of the substring in a string, which i can kind of do.
right now i have this:

```
sub = "rth"
str = "zrwhqtho"

first_letter = sub[0]
last_letter = sub[-1]

start = None
end = None

letters = [let for let in str]

for i, letter in enumerate(letters):
    if letter == first_letter:
        start = i
    if letter == last_letter:
        end = i

if start and end:
    print(f"From %s to %s." % (start + 1, end + 1))
```

it prints "From 2 to 7." the issue here is that in the main string there are 2 h letters, and the program takes the one that comes after the t. how do i make it so that it will only take the first occurrence of a letter instead of taking the last letter?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, call the variable something other than `str`, since you are overwriting a built-in keyword this way. I renamed it to `string`.

Note that `start and end` is `False` if `first_letter` is the first letter in `string`, ie at index 0, meaning `start == 0 == False`.

The easiest solution is to use the built-in function `str.find`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

```
sub = "rth"
string = "zrwhqtho"

first_letter = sub[0]
last_letter = sub[-1]

start = string.find(first_letter)
if start != -1: # string.find returns -1 if first_letter is not found
    end = string.find(last_letter, start)
    # Only checks the string after start, ensures that end > start
else:
    end = -1

if end != -1:
    # End is -1 only if either first_letter is not in the string, or there is no last_letter in the string after first_letter
    print(f"From %s to %s." % (start + 1, end + 1))
```